# SwiftMailer Spool Transport

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, spool

In symfony 2, if I create a new swiftmessage instance I can give the transport in it.

```
$email = \Swift_Message::newInstance( $transport )
```

But how to put the transport in it and how to configure? (like spool path)

I tried:

```
$transport = new \Swift_Transport_SpoolTransport();
```

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Swift_Transport_SpoolTransport::__construct() must be an instance of Swift_Events_EventDispatcher, none given, called in /Users/mitchel/Projecten/Refurls/src/Refurl/FrontendBundle/Controller/MessageController.php on line 67 and defined in /Users/mitchel/Projecten/Refurls/vendor/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/SpoolTransport.php line 27

so I think I don't use the right class. Who can push me the right way? =)

---

The next code also send it directly

```
$transport = new \Swift_FileSpool( '../app/spool' );
$email = \Swift_Message::newInstance( $transport )
```

I figured out that the Swift_Message doesn't expect a tranport.

```
public function __construct($subject = null, $body = null,
    $contentType = null, $charset = null)
```

It would be nice to give a Transport. The reason that I don't want to configure it in the config is that if I create 2 services and 1 with:

```
<argument type="service" id="swiftmailer.transport.real" />
```

This transport.real will ignore the swiftmailer.delivery_address.

Answer (score 1):

the `Swift_Transport_SpoolTransport` requires two arguments (source: http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/class-Swift_Transport_SpoolTransport.html):

1. Swift_Events_EventDispatcher $eventDispatcher
2. Swift_Spool $spool = null

For the first argument I used this class:

```
new \Swift_Events_SimpleEventDispatcher();
```

Simplez!

Answer (score 0):

You do all the [configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html) in the `config.yml` file and create a message without passing anything to the factory method:

```php
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
```

Comment: No this mail will send it directly, I want to give the spool transport so he will spool it. And I don't want to configure the spool in my config.